# Update label when a variable changes

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm creating a clicker game which, when you purchase a certain upgrade, will add to a counter and update a label.

This will only run correctly if the user causes a window update.

If you wait then click, the time you've waited multiplied by the score per second will be added. I want it updating without the user having to be at their computer.

Here is what I tried. This code doesn't work.

```
def votesPerSecond():
    global Votes
    global VPC
    global VPS
    while Votes >= 0:
        Votes += VPS
        time.sleep(1)

def updateSB():
    while True:
        score_label.text = "Votes: " + str(Votes) + "\nVotes/Click: " + str(VPC) + "\nVotes/Sec: " + str(VPS) + "\nUPGRADES:\n1 - 100 Votes for +1 Vote/Click\n2 - 10000 Votes for +10 Votes/Sec"
        time.sleep(1)

threadA = threading.Thread(target=updateSB)
threadB = threading.Thread(target=votesPerSecond)
threadA.start()
threadB.start()
```

Comment: btw: pyglet has [sheduler](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/pyglet.clock.html) which can execute function periodically and then you don't need threads,sleep() and while loop.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks really helped!